# R package installation fail from source

Tags: r, package, rcpp

I am trying to install a home-made package in R. It installs OK on two computers, but on another, I get this error message:

```
Error in rawToChar(block[seq_len(ns)]) :

  embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\024\0\0\0\b\0יxיPװ\331Qbב\037\0\0\337%\0\0\r\0\0\0[Content].tarםZeX\034\335\025^,$xp‡אממ\301%8\004\b÷Xp[$¸»\004\r.\301\002‹»\023\\ƒ»\005w‡ !H7\375\332¦´M\373פO\177uז'

Warning in install.packages :
```

Is there a fix? What can cause the problem?

The packages is written mostly in `RcppArmadillo`, with some extra C++ packages. When I use the check option I get no errors nor warnings.

Comment: This is almost surely local to your computer as Rcpp installs fine at CRAN and everywhere else. Also, we call it `RcppArmadillo`.  Capital R Capital A rest lowercase.

Comment: I'm not installing Rcpp but some package I wrote. It installs fine on most computers, i'm trying to understand what can cause the problem..